# Signal_draw in Gtkmm2.4

Tags: c++, drawing, signals, cairo, gtkmm

I'm trying to compile a gtkmm application that uses cairomm for drawing.
It compiles fine using gtkmm3.0 but when I try to compile it using gtkmm2.4 i get:

> error: ‘signal_draw’ was not declared in this scope

I'm using g++.

It seems that there is no signal_draw in gtkmm2.4(Am I wrong?). Is there any function/signal that can be used instead?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my bad English.

Some code:

> class egclass: public Gtk::DrawingArea
>
> {
>
> public:
>
> egclass();
>
> virtual ~egclass();
>
> ```
> virtual bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr);
> ```
>
> };
>
> egclass::egclass()
>
> {
>
> #ifndef GLIBMM_DEFAULT_SIGNAL_HANDLERS_ENABLED
>
> signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &egclass::on_draw), false);
>
> #endif
>
> }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The older gtkmm 2.4 has [on_expose_event](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/2.24/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a95336d2ed3b47fb8e63f76e9fe96d520) instead:

```
virtual bool on_expose_event(GdkEventExpose* event);
```

If you need to create a cairo context for drawing, with the GTK+ C API it goes something like this:

```
cairo_t *cr;

cr = gdk_cairo_create (event->window);
gdk_cairo_region (cr, event->region);
cairo_clip (cr);

/* do your drawing */

cairo_destroy (cr);
```

... translating the snippet above to gtkmm is left as an exercise to the reader.

Also see the following links:

- [Porting from gtkmm-2.4 to gtkmm-3.0](https://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/PortingToGtkmm3)
- [Migrating from GTK+ 2.x to GTK+ 3](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html)
- [example_pixbufs.cc](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/tree/demos/gtk-demo/example_pixbufs.cc?h=gtkmm-2-24#n127)

Comment: Ok, but still I need a Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> to perform a drawing, how can I get it?